# Is it necessary to write to a backup file if the original will not be truncated?

Tags: php, database

So I have the following function:

```
public function append(array $data) {
    $this->connect('ab');
    if(flock($this->_pointer, LOCK_EX)) {
        fwrite($this->_pointer, $this->cleanInput($data));
        $this->unlock();
        $this->disconnect();
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->disconnect();
        return false;
    }
}
```

It writes a string to the end of a file. The file is opened for writing but not truncated and the pointer is put directly at the end of the file.

My question is whether it is necessary to `copy()` the file that is being written to a temporary location, write to that file and replace the original file even though I am not truncating the file?

What is the potential for data loss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the short answer to this is "No".

With the current approach, you are acquiring an exclusive lock before modifying the file's data. This means that no other process will be able to modify the file while you have this lock (within the provisions of advisory locking). One thing that is notable is that you do not test whether `fwrite()` was successful, which you probably should do if you are concerned about data loss.

If you copy the file and write to the copied file, there are two problems:

- The process will take much longer, especially if the file is very large.
- You no longer have your exclusive lock on the original file, so if somebody else tries to modify the file while you are doing this, you may overwrite their modification when you copy the file back.

If you did want to make a backup of the file before the copy operation, that is what you should do - make a backup. But you still modify the original file, not the copy. And if it fails, replace the original with the backup, so that the original is effectively unmodified.

Really it seems to me that all of this is unnecessary - creating a backup before *every* write operation is *extremely* pessimistic and will result in a much less efficient system overall, especially since you are acquiring an exclusive lock on the file before performing any operations on it. But what you definitely should be doing is testing the result of your `fwrite()` call.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I should of mentioned this is a database system and you hit the nail on the head for why I don't want to write to backups because of speed. I like the idea of creating a copy then testing for success of `fwrite()` and then if `fwrite()` fails replace the original with the copy.

Comment: I suspected it may be a database - this is the usual reason for this sort of thing. It should be noted that pure-PHP databases tend to be extremely inefficient compared to external alternatives - you should look at [SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php), which is available in pretty much every PHP 5 installation.

Comment: Not in mine :P The database is pretty efficient in terms of speed currently atleast for the size I am using. Won't be more than a few thousand records.